# CMake with ios framework

Tags: c++, ios, cmake, sdk, frameworks

I developing an ios framework which using CMake. I write the below scripts in CMakeLists.txt so that I can use command `cmake` to produce `.xcodeproj` directory so that I can use it in xcode.

```
set(LIB_NAME mylib)
set(LIB_TYPE STATIC)
file(GLOB_RECURSE EXTRA_FILES platform/ios/*.mm platform/ios/*.m platform/ios/*.h)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES
        "src/*.cpp"
        "src/*.c"
        "src/*.h"
        "src/*.hpp")

source_group(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FILES ${SOURCE_FILES})

add_library(${LIB_NAME} ${LIB_TYPE} ${SOURCE_FILES} ${EXTRA_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${LIB_NAME} ${LIBEVENT} ${LIBxxx} ${EXTRA_LIBS})

file(GLOB_RECURSE IOS_PUBLIC_HEADERS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/platform/ios/*.h")
set_target_properties(${LIB_NAME} PROPERTIES
            FRAMEWORK TRUE
            MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_IDENTIFIER xxxx.xxxx
            MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_INFO_PLIST 
            ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/platform/ios/Info.plist
            PUBLIC_HEADER "${IOS_PUBLIC_HEADERS}"
            XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "iPhone Developer"
            )
```

and after I type this command in cli, I can generate an IOS framwork in Products directory.

`cmake ../.. -GXcode -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../../ios.toolchain.cmake`

The variable `IOS_PUBLIC_HEADERS` contains some header files that I want someone to use who use my framework. The problem is when I use the framework in my demo, the compile says:

`"view/Baseview.h" file not found.`

Some header file in `IOS_PUBLIC_HEADERS` variable use directive `import <view/Baseview.h>` to use my internal header file which I don't want my client user to include.

anyone can help?

thank you anyway, forgive my poor english.

Comment: "Some header file in `IOS_PUBLIC_HEADERS` variable use directive `import <view/Baseview.h>` to use my internal header file which I don't want my client user to include." - This is what you should avoid. Public headers should include only other public headers.

Comment: got it, i use it in my implementation file